# Polymorphism in C++ never upcasts

Tags: c++

I have been a java developer for a long time. Im sure Im thinking of this the wrong way.

But I have a class Animal and a class Dog. Dog extends animal and in my main, I make a bunch of dogs and stick them into a vector of Animals.

While iterating over them, I can not access Dog specific methods on objects that where originally dogs.

What am I doing wrong?

**Animal**

```
 #include "Header.h"
class Animal {
    std::string name;
    int age;
public:
    std::string getName(){ return name;}
    virtual int getAge(){ return age;}
    virtual int getRealAge();
    Animal(std::string name, int age);
    ~Animal();

};

Animal::Animal(std::string name, int age){
    this->name = name;
    this->age = age;
}

int Animal::getRealAge() {
    return this->age*100/2;
}

Animal::~Animal() {

}
```

**Dog**

```
#include "Header.h"
class Dog : public Animal {
public :
    Dog(std::string name, int age);
    ~Dog();
    int getAge();

};

Dog::Dog(std::string name, int age) : Animal::Animal(name, age) {

}

Dog::~Dog(){

}

int Dog::getAge() {
    return Animal::getAge()*7;
}
```

**Main**

```
#include "Header.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    // I make a bunch of Dogs
    Dog tmp0("Ellie", 1);
    Dog tmp5("sam", 2);
    Dog tmp4("lindsay", 3);
    Dog tmp3("shilo", 4);
    Dog tmp2("rex", 5);
    Dog tmp1("bob", 6);
    Animal tmp00("nick", 11);

    vector<Animal*> animals;

    animals.push_back(&tmp0); // Dog is-an Animal
    animals.push_back(&tmp1);
    animals.push_back(&tmp2);
    animals.push_back(&tmp3);
    animals.push_back(&tmp4);
    animals.push_back(&tmp5);
    animals.push_back(&tmp00); //new

    for(auto &animal : animals){
        Animal *tmp = NULL;
        if (typeid(animal) == typeid(Animal)){
            cout << "Found animal" << endl;
        }else{
            cout << "Found animal" << endl;
            cout << animal->getName() << " is " << animal->getAge() << endl;
        }



    }


    return 0;
};
```

**output**

```
Found Dog
Ellie is 1
Found Dog
bob is 6
Found Dog
rex is 5
Found Dog
shilo is 4
Found Dog
lindsay is 3
Found Dog
sam is 2
Found Dog
nick is 11
```

But they all should be multiplied by 7.

**EDIT**

I added the virtual type to the methods in the Animal class above and added an Object of type Animal to my vector.

However, in the for loop in the main, the object returns as type dog as well.

Comment: I think you've forgot to declare getAge() method as virtual.

Comment: In Java, every method is effectively virtual and can be overridden (unless declared `final`); in C++, only virtual methods can be overridden.

Comment: You never call `Dog::getAge()` only `Animal::getAge()` because you are using an `Animal` pointer. As the others said, make `getAge()` virtual in the base class to get Java behaviour (overriding).

Comment: Also make the Animal destructor virtual so subtypes are correctly destroyed from any base pointer.

Comment: Output and code mismatch.

Comment: @Galik: You said I never call Dog::getAge(); Isn't that the point of polymorphism. I shouldnt have to declare which getAge I get.

Comment: @Basilevs: What do you mean?

Comment: @Cripto The point is you have a choice in C++ whether to use polymorphism or not. You make that choice by declaring the function virtual or not. If you don't you choose to call Animal::getAge().

Comment: @Cripto Output says Dog is found. No string "Dog" is ever referenced in the code.

Comment: In Java all methods are virtual, if you want to implement polymorphism you have to declare the methods virtual.  Also, if you are treating with animals, you have only access to animal methods, you have to cast the object to a Dog to use Dog::methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making getAge virtual is the sane option, but it's at least passingly noteworthy that you can get the behaviour you wanted by replacing...

```
    if (typeid(animal) == typeid(Animal)){
        cout << "Found animal" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "Found animal" << endl;
        cout << animal->getName() << " is " << animal->getAge() << endl;
    }
```

...with...

```
    if (Dog* p = dynamic_cast<Dog*>(&animal))
    {
        // inside here, p is known to be a Dog* at compile time, so
        // getAge() is statically dispatched to Dog::getAge
        cout << "Found animal/dog" << endl;
        cout << p->getName() << " is " << p->getAge() << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "Found animal" << endl;
    }
```

This `dynamic_cast<>` would be considered a bit of an anti-pattern in C++ (it's crazy for every client code site using `getAge()` to have to know about the derived classes' specifics), with the `virtual` function being the better approach.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make `getAge` a virtual function.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function

Comment: You were correct. But the change cause another issue. Can you address that. Made the change in the main code and added an **edit** note

Comment: @Cripto You changed the question and now the answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: The code is messed up now too.  It always returns Found Animal.   FTW: Remember a dog ISA Animal.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, what you mean by the words `in the for loop in the main, the object returns as type dog as well`. If you do mean, that condition of `typeid(animal) == typeid(Animal)` never holds, than this is exactly, how it is supposed to work, as [typeid](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) will return most derived dynamic type of object.

Instead of `typeid` I would recommend you writing a polymorphic function, that will accept the most appropriate object. I. e. you can write

```
void animal_test(Dog& dog)
{
    /* this will be called when argument is Dog or its ancestor… */
}

void animal_test(Animal& any)
{
    /* this will be called in all other cases */
}
```

As for virtual functions, this is a main difference between Java and C++ in that in C++ functions are not virtual by default. If your function is not virtual (at least at some point in class hierarchy, higher, than pointer to object used to call that function), which function will be called depends solely on pointer type.